# Reading JavaScript variable in Ruby through curl request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I need to read the GBP rate from this javascript file: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js. I want to be able to get the js variable as `JSON` so that I can easily access the variable I need with its index. I tried a couple of ways as follows with eventually no success.

## Way 1

Source: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html

My code:

```
uri = URI('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js')

@response = Net::HTTP.get(uri) # => String
```

Result: I get the result as a string and reading the GBP rate from the string is difficult and probably not the correct way.

## Way 2

Source: [curl request in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532792/curl-request-in-ruby)

My Code:

```
url = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js'
mykey = 'demo'
uri = URI(url)

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
request['Accept'] = 'application/xml'
request['X-OFFERSDB-API-KEY'] = mykey

@response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

Result: This returns me Net::HTTP:0x007f2480874050 which looks like a memory address, definitely not what I want.

In addition, I've included require 'net/http', require 'json' in my controller in either case.

I am very new to Ruby and I don't know how to figure this out. So looking for someone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a weird request, IMO, but Rails can do it. Rails comes with a library called [execjs](https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme) automatically, which lets you run javascript from ruby. So, you have some javascript you want to run in that file, but you also want to return specific key from that javascript, so something like this should do it:

```
# Expanding upon 'Way 1', which got you the javascript as a string
uri = URI('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js')
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)

gbp_rate = ExecJS.exec "#{response}; return Currency.rates.GBP;"
p gbp_rate # => 1.40045
```

I just want to reiterate (from their FAQ in the README) though:

> Can ExecJS be used to sandbox scripts?
>
> No, ExecJS shouldn't be used for any security related sandboxing. Since runtimes are automatically detected, each runtime has different sandboxing properties. You shouldn't use ExecJS.eval on any inputs you wouldn't feel comfortable Ruby eval()ing.

This file looks safe, but just keep it in mind, you are actually executing this javascript.

Personally, I would look to see if there's an API somewhere that can give you this value more easily, or if it doesn't change often (I have never used Shopify so don't know how much this changes) just hardcode it in the app as a config value and update it manually. Just feels cleaner, to me.

Comment: This definitely has solved the problem. Thank you for your time and effort.